# Unable to read DVDs (.VRO files) with Apple USB SuperDrive

Tags: usb, video, optical-drive, dvd

I'm attempting to play some DVDs using an [Apple USB SuperDrive](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/MD564LL/A/apple-usb-superdrive) and [HandBrake](https://handbrake.fr). The DVDs are burned (non-original) containing various Japanese language children's shows.

Here is some information about my system:

```
System hardware info:

Model Name: MacBook Pro
Model Identifier: MacBookPro18,1
Model Number: MK183H/A
Chip: Apple M1 Pro
Total Number of Cores: 10 (8 performance and 2 efficiency)
Memory: 16 GB
System Firmware Version: 8419.80.7
OS Loader Version: 8419.80.7

System software info:

System Version: macOS 13.2.1 (22D68)
Kernel Version: Darwin 22.3.0

Apple USB SuperDrive hardware info:

Product ID: 0x1500
Vendor ID: 0x05ac (Apple Inc.)
Version: 2.03
Speed: Up to 480 Mb/s
Manufacturer: Apple Inc.
Location ID: 0x00100000 / 1
Current Available (mA): 500
Current Required (mA): 500
Extra Operating Current (mA): 600
Media:
SuperDrive:
  Capacity: 4,35 GB (4 354 867 200 bytes)
  Removable Media: Yes
  BSD Name: disk4
  Logical Unit: 0
  Media Name: TSB0003
  Partition Map Type: Unknown
  S.M.A.R.T. status: Verified
  USB Interface: 0
```

And here is an example of what a DVD looks like:

```
/Volumes/TSB0003/.
├── ADV_OBJ
│   └── TSB_MENU
│       ├── TNLR0000.ACA
│       └── TNSM0000.ACA
├── DVD_RTAV
│   ├── VR_MANGR.BUP
│   ├── VR_MANGR.IFO
│   └── VR_MOVIE.VRO
├── TS_MANGR
│   ├── ACA_THMNLTSGI.IFO
│   ├── DISC.IFO
│   ├── FOLDER.IFO
│   ├── R_THMNL.IFO
│   ├── TSGI.IFO
│   ├── TTDETAIL.IFO
│   ├── TTLUTLTY.IFO
│   └── TTL_PROP.IFO
└── TS_THMNL
```

HandBrake fails to read these DVDs. I'm also unable to open them using VLC and Apple's QuickTime Player or DVD Player apps. Nothing seems to be able to read these DVDs.

Here is the verbose log from HandHrake:

```
Starting HandBrake software:

[10:29:19] macgui: Handbrake Version: 1.6.1 (2023012200)
[10:29:19] Compile-time hardening features are enabled
[10:29:19] hb_init: starting libhb thread
[10:29:19] thread 16f84f000 started ("libhb")

When attempting to load VR_MOVIE.VRO with HandBrake:

[10:29:35] macgui: ScanCore scanning titles with a duration of 10 seconds or more
[10:29:35] CPU: 
[10:29:35]  - logical processor count: 10
[10:29:35] hb_scan: path=/Volumes/TSB0003/DVD_RTAV/VR_MOVIE.VRO, title_index=0
[10:29:35] thread 16f507000 started ("scan")
udfread ERROR: ECMA 167 Volume Recognition failed
disc.c:333: failed opening UDF image /Volumes/TSB0003/DVD_RTAV/VR_MOVIE.VRO
disc.c:437: error opening file BDMV/index.bdmv
disc.c:437: error opening file BDMV/BACKUP/index.bdmv
[10:29:35] bd: not a bd - trying as a stream/file instead
libdvdread: DVDOpenFileUDF:UDFFindFile /VIDEO_TS/VIDEO_TS.IFO failed
libdvdnav: vm: vm: failed to read VIDEO_TS.IFO
[10:29:35] dvd: not a dvd - trying as a stream/file instead
[10:29:35] file is MPEG Program Stream
[10:29:53] Probing 1 unknown stream
[10:29:53]     Probe: Unsupported stream . stream id 0xe0-0x0
[10:29:53] Found the following streams
[10:29:53]     Video Streams : 
[10:29:53]     Audio Streams : 
[10:29:53]       0xbd-0x80 type AC3 (0x81)
[10:29:53]     Subtitle Streams : 
[10:29:53]     Other Streams : 
[10:29:53]       0xe0-0x0 type Unknown (0x0)
[10:29:53] stream id 0xbd (type 0x81 substream 0x80) audio 0x8000bd
[10:29:53] Freed 1 buffers of size 4096
[10:29:53] Freed 3 buffers of size 2097152
[10:29:53] Allocated 6295552 bytes of buffers on this pass and Freed 6295552 bytes, 0 bytes leaked
[10:29:53] thread 16f507000 exited ("scan")
[10:29:53] thread 16f507000 joined ("scan")
[10:29:53] libhb: scan thread found 0 valid title(s)
[10:29:53] macgui: ScanCore scan done

When attempting to load VR_MANGR.IFO with HandBrake:

[10:30:07] macgui: ScanCore scanning titles with a duration of 10 seconds or more
[10:30:07] CPU: 
[10:30:07]  - logical processor count: 10
[10:30:07] hb_scan: path=/Volumes/TSB0003/DVD_RTAV/VR_MANGR.IFO, title_index=0
[10:30:07] thread 16f7c3000 started ("scan")
udfread ERROR: ECMA 167 Volume Recognition failed
disc.c:333: failed opening UDF image /Volumes/TSB0003/DVD_RTAV/VR_MANGR.IFO
disc.c:437: error opening file BDMV/index.bdmv
disc.c:437: error opening file BDMV/BACKUP/index.bdmv
[10:30:08] bd: not a bd - trying as a stream/file instead
libdvdread: DVDOpenFileUDF:UDFFindFile /VIDEO_TS/VIDEO_TS.IFO failed
libdvdnav: vm: vm: failed to read VIDEO_TS.IFO
[10:30:08] dvd: not a dvd - trying as a stream/file instead
[10:30:08] hb_stream_open: open /Volumes/TSB0003/DVD_RTAV/VR_MANGR.IFO failed
[10:30:08] scan: unrecognized file type
[10:30:08] Allocated 0 bytes of buffers on this pass and Freed 0 bytes, 0 bytes leaked
[10:30:08] thread 16f7c3000 exited ("scan")
[10:30:08] thread 16f7c3000 joined ("scan")
[10:30:08] libhb: scan thread found 0 valid title(s)
[10:30:08] macgui: ScanCore scan done
```

I also have `libdvdcss` (version 1.4.3) installed on my system (via Homebrew).

Does anyone know what's going wrong here and how to read these DVDs?

[Here's a relevant issue](https://github.com/HandBrake/HandBrake/issues/5328) I filed under HandBrake on GitHub.

Comment: Do you have another DVD reader (Windows, commercial DVD player) you can test on? You might consider purchasing an inexpensive DVD external reader/writer like [this one](https://www.amazon.com/LG-Electronics-Portable-Rewriter-GP60NB50/dp/B00C2AMK2M).

Comment: Unfortunately not :'( I just bought the Apple USB SuperDrive yesterday. I'll try to find another one for testing.

Comment: Have you tried MakeMKV? I've found it to be more robust than Handbrake, and it is available for macOS.

Comment: I have not tried that one! Thanks for the tip; I'll give it a go.